# How to find the gcd of this polynomial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What would the GCD of $3n + 2$ and $4n + 3$ be using Euclid's algorithm

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Note that $$-4(3n+2)+3(4n+3)=1$$

Comment: Probably the point of the exercise was to learn how to use the Euclidean algorithm symbolically - as instructed "by using Euclid's algorithm" (see Brett's answer). This gives the gcd without needing to obtain the above Bezout identity (i.e. without using the *extended* Euclidean algorithm).

Comment: @MathGems: Yes and that's why I prefer Brett answer than mine. I tried to solve it by using Bézout's identity. You are right. +1 for him.

Comment: That's not to say that other methods aren't useful. For example, the above apporach may be generalized to show that $\rm\: A(n,1)\:$ is a coprime pair for any $2 \times 2$ integer matrix $\rm\,A\,$ with determinant $ = 1,$ e.g. see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/297774/23500)

Comment: I like this...it's good to have different approaches+1

Answer (score 3):

$$4n+3=(3n+2)+(n+1)$$
$$(3n+2)=3\cdot(n+1)-1$$

Since the remainder is $\pm 1$, the GCD is $1$.

Alternatively, note that the greatest common divisor must divide both numbers, as well as their difference. So if $d$ is the GCD, $d|(n+1)$. But $(n+1)$ cannot share any factors with $(4n+3)=4\cdot(n+1)-1$.

Comment: I hope the OP didn't mislead by my very short  answer.